# How to merge two divs

Tags: css

I have two divs which should looks like one figure. The problem is with the border of the circular block. See pic. below. css were added below

[image: input and output needed]

```
#nameWidgeteMain {
  width: 279px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(237,237,237);
  border: 1px solid #dbe0e3;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)
}
.nameWidgeteCloseArea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 22px;
  height: 31px;
  top: 7px;
  left: 270px;
  background-color: rgb(237,237,237);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #dbe0e3;
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-top-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#nameWidgeteCloseTitle {
  padding-top: 5px;
  left: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
}
```

Comment: is the round effect just for the drawing or not ? There is no way to 'merge' but you can use some trickery like a 0-sized border on the left.

Comment: yes, I will try to play with this side of the border.

Comment: You could have a go with the z-index. Have the round div "under" the vertical line and then another div for the content.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/VNAZA/

Uses two divs: one with just the border, which gets layered under the rectangle and another with the actual content, layering over the rectangle. This way you can also apply css box-shadow to the lower div.

```css
.container{
        position:relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    
    .rect{
        position:absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 150px;
        background: #eee;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        z-index: 5;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px #cccccc;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px #cccccc;
    }
    
    .round_content{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
        right: -25px;
        width: 50px;
        line-height: 50px;
        background: #eee;
        z-index: 6;
        text-align:center;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    
    .round_border{
        position: absolute;
        top: 49px;
        right: -26px;
        width: 52px;
        height: 50px;
        line-height: 52px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        z-index: 4;
        text-align: center;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px #cccccc;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 2px #cccccc;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="rect"></div>
      <div class="round_content">x</div>
      <div class="round_border"></div>
    </div>
```

​

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with CSS.

Solution A) involves graphics used as background and solution B) uses a layer behind the vertical bar to draw the oval, a second layer for the bar itself and a third DIV for the X and it's link.

Comment: Surely the second solution IS CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I meant you can't "merge" two borders into one using CSS. The second solution is a workaround to achieve an optical equivalent to what was desired…

Comment: Ah ok. That makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

Use [z-index property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

```
#nameWidgeteMain, #nameWidgeteMain2 {
  width: 279px;
  height: 400px;
  top: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(237,237,237);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)
}

#nameWidgeteMain2 {
  z-index: -2;
  border: 1px solid #dbe0e3;
}

.nameWidgeteCloseArea {
  z-index: -1;
  ...
}
```

This is not merging but the result is the same.

Comment: But now first div border will be visible.

Comment: You're right. You may add another div identical to #nameWidgeteMain with borders and z-index: -2 and remove borders from #nameWidgeteMain.