# Merge Two "DIV" and Box Shadow

Tags: merge, division, css

Is this possible to merge a round and a square div and show single box-shadow in css3? I know we can hide single side of border of any div. But my need is different:

**[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQpgq.jpg)**

If this is possible, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You can try it with 3 Divs and zIndex. Set up horizonal Box first, then the circle and then a div without any shadow over the other elements.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11190821/3548826) answer could be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you actually only need a single `div`, then can make use of positioning on its `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements (the below CSS is a starting point):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/90d7144p/5/)

CSS

```
div, div:before {
    height:50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #424242;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 #424242;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:200px;
}
div:before {
    height:100px;
    margin-top:0;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:-25px;
    left:100px;
    content:'';
    border-radius:100%;
}
div:after {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    background:white;
    position:absolute;
    top:-0;
    left:0;
    content:'';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i come with [**a very similar answer**](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/kgvot). with the use of z-index to make sure it works fine and that eventually, content is seen :)

```
<div class="shaped"> </div>
```

CSS

```
.shaped {
  margin:2em 0;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;/* will be inherited by pseudo under */
  height:2em;
  position:relative;
  background:white;/* will be inherited by pseudo on top */
}
.shaped:before, .shaped:after {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  height:2em;
  width:2em;
  padding:1em;
  background:inherit;
  border-radius:100%;
  margin:-1em 2em;
  z-index:1;
}
.shaped:before {
  box-shadow:inherit;
  z-index:-1;
}
.shaped>* {/* let's see whatever comes inside */
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
```