# How to merge div cells

Tags: html, css

I want to merge the div with text called `XXXXXxxxXXXX`with div which you can see above. I dont see there is colspan property as table has. Also i need to add overflow to that row.

Here is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7233ws1g/)

Has someone idea how to fix this?

Expected output should be something like below . Also column with text "XXXX" should have overflow

[image]

Comment: Read this other thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190488/how-to-merge-two-divs . Maybe can help you

Comment: @Charly66  i need to merge column with text "XXXxxxxXXX" to 3 columns.. above row is 4 column

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML colspan in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css)

Comment: What is the motivation behind trying to construct a table using divs, why not simply use a table?

Comment: As it all depends on how the rest of the table will look like, can you give a hint and I will suggest a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.dtable { 
    display:table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width:529px;    
}

.drow { 
    display:table-row; 
    width:525px;    
}

.dcell {
    display:table-cell; 
    border:1px solid gray;
}


#D_Cell_1 {
    width:100px;
}

#Description {
    width:100px;
    height:58px;
}

#Des_Content{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    position: absolute;
    height:58px;
    width:425px;
}
```

```html
<div id='main_wrapper' class='dtable'>
    <div id='control_panel_wrapper' class='drow'>
        <div id='D_Cell_1' class='dcell'>Title</div>
        <div id='D_Cell_2' class='dcell'>Manager marketing</div>
        <div id='D_Cell_3' class='dcell'>Application Deadline</div>
        <div id='D_Cell_4' class='dcell'>22.04.2012</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='dtable'>
    <div id='bottom_wrapper' class='drow'>
        <div id='Description' class='dcell'>Description</div>
        <div id='Des_Content' class='dcell'>LOREM IPSUM
dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to fix that code as id´s is suppose to be unique

Comment: you have shifted text "manager marketing" it should align to second row with text "XXXXXXXXX"

Comment: your updated code has still shifted text manager marketing to right. It should align left to text XXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: This first update just to change ID's, as LGSon said

Comment: i dont see any duplicated id in your code. is it possible to left align text manager marketing to text xxxxx and provide overflow to text XXXXX ?

Comment: is it possible to have overflow to text XXXXXXX?

Comment: did you mean add scroll-x to this cell or multi-lines ?

Comment: @Happy refer to last update using _table-layout: fixed;_ and _overflow-x_

Comment: sorry my bad.. i meant vertical scroll. I tried to change to Y but it gives horizontal scroll. I only want vertical scroll

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109986/discussion-between-happy-and-shady-alset).

Answer (score 0):

Add the next css

```
/*Row 1, Cell 2*/
.divTableRow:nth-child(1) .divTableCell:nth-child(2) {
  border-bottom-width : 0; /*Not border bottom*/
}

/*Row 2, Cell 2 */
.divTableRow:nth-child(2) .divTableCell:nth-child(2){
  border-top-width: 0; /*Not border top*/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L9qh5o78/

Comment: Nope the text "XXXXxxXXX" should span 3 columns

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, you can't use colspans and rowspans if you are creating tables using `display:table`.

[Here](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout#toc-some-limitations-or-issues) is some more information

Alternatives -

1) Use HTML table instead(Recommended)

2) See how W3Schools have implemented it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp)