# merge divs with same value

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to merge the divs that have the same number in order to see the week and its number.

[image]

This is how my html looks like

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
        <div class="left">
            <label class="kw">WeekNo.</label>
        </div>
        <div class="right week-number" *ngFor="let day of days">
            <label class="number-label"><span>{{day.weekNumber}} </span></label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

do I have to use `*ngIf` or just css? 
I have read this [How to merge two divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190488/how-to-merge-two-divs), but I don't know where ti include the `if` statement

this is the class I am using

```
export class Day {
    number: number;
    weekDay: number;
    name: string;
    weekNumber: number;

    constructor(number: number, weekDay: number, name: string, weekNumber: number
       ) {
            this.number = number;
            this.weekDay = weekDay;
            this.name = name;
            this.weekNumber = weekNumber;
        }
}
```

and this is how it should look afet merging
[image]

Comment: With css you can solve this easily, playing around with borders and padding/margin

Comment: can you make it much more clearer , are you tying group  items with same week number  , also post your data object or array

Comment: i want to group items with same week number

Comment: Please click `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Comment: @celamoet can you provide the days array sample in the following stackblitz demo  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4yscse

Comment: the simplest IMO would be to create a new array `weeks` in your controller with a width property based on the number of aggregated days, and do your `ngFor` on it..

Comment: @celamoet can you provide a sample days array in the above demo so that i can  work on it

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1kfbod?file=src/app/app.component.css , here is the complete example @JoelJoseph

Comment: @celamoet please check the demo link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwzz5g

Comment: @celamoet did you check the demo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the following way by creating a groupBy pipe and including Bootstrap 4 in the project. Here is a plain working demo (you will have to do the styling) [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gwzz5g):

**groupby.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'groupBy'})
export class GroupByPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(collection: any[], property: string): any[] {
        // prevents the application from breaking if the array of objects doesn't exist yet
        if(!collection) {
            return null;
        }

        const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
            if(!previous[current[property]]) {
                previous[current[property]] = [current];
            } else {
                previous[current[property]].push(current);
            }

            return previous;
        }, {});

        // this will return an array of objects, each object containing a group of objects
        return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
    }
}
```

**html code**

```
<div class="table table-borderless ">
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center border"><span>{{currentMonthName}}</span>&nbsp; <span>{{currentYear}}</span></div>

    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class=" text-center m-2 border" *ngFor="let day of days | groupBy:'weekNumber'">
        {{day.key}}
      <table class="table">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"  *ngFor="let x of day.value ">{{x.number}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row"  *ngFor="let y of day.value ">{{y.name}}</th>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```