# Can you merge to contents of one div element with another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have two `<div>` elements in my web app and I would like to get the contents of both and put them into a single new element. I have tried doing this in multiple ways but I am having trouble doing this without a huge lump of spaghetti code and variables. does anyone have a simple way of achieving this?

Note (from future me):
sorry, I wrote this so badly when I was younger, I tried to rephrase it so maybe others can gain something from the answers.

Comment: What does "merge a div tag" even mean?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: combine two or more div tags to create one.

Comment: You want to take the content from one `div` and append it to the content of another `div`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190488/how-to-merge-two-divs Something like this?

Comment: /html
            <dive id='one'></div>
            <dive id='two'></div>

            /js
            var 1 =$('#one').html
             var 2 = $('#two').html
            $('#1').html(1+2)

Comment: like `<div> some info </div> <div> some other info </div>`  to `<div> some info,  some other info </div>`? If so, programatically, or in your IDE?

Comment: thank you, Jeremy Lucas, that will work

Comment: @andrewtaggart are you sure that will work....thats a CSS question...doesnt seem to have anything to do with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realise that this is an old question at this point, but since it suddenly appeared on the homepage – and I saw the existing answer – I thought I'd offer another approach, using plain JavaScript:

```js
// I don't enjoy typing all that much, so these are a couple of utilities to avoid
// typing 'document' and 'document.querySelector(...)':
const D = document,
  get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector),
  // a simple named function, written using Arrow function syntax (as there's no
  // need to use 'this');
  // the function takes three arguments, the first of which is the
  // startNode: a reference to a node in the document, and
  // n: an Integer which is the number of siblings in the document you wish to
  // 'merge' together; this has a default argument of 0 which means the function
  // does nothing,
  // elementsOnly: Boolean, default of true; if this is true we only worry about
  // merging element-nodes (<div>,<p>...) into the startNode; if false then we
  // also merge text-nodes, comment-nodes, etc:
  merge = (startNode, n = 0, elementsOnly = true) => {
 // if there is no startNode (or startNode is falsey), we quit the function:
if (!startNode) {
      return false;
    }
    // otherwise we initialise a counter from the supplied variable of 'n',
    // we use parseInt(), with a radix of 10 (for base-10 numbering), on
    // the supplied number in case it's somehow a string, or a number in
    // another base:
    let counter = parseInt(n, 10),
      nodeTypes = elementsOnly === true ? 'nextElementSibling' : 'nextSibling';
      
      // while the counter variable is truthy:
    while (counter) {
    
    // we assign either the startNode node's next element-sibling (if
      // elementsOnly is equal to true) or the next sibling node (if
      // elementsOnly is equal to false):
      let next = startNode[nodeTypes];
      
      // if there is no next-sibling node we break out of the while loop:
      if (!next) {
        break;
      }
      
      // if the nodeType of the 'next' node is
      // equal to 1 (so the node is an element-
      // node):
      if (next.nodeType === 1) {
        // while the element-node has a first-child:
        while (next.firstChild) {
            // we append that first-child to the startNode:
          startNode.append(next.firstChild);
        }
        // once emptied, we remove the 'next' node:
        next.remove();
        
      // otherwise:
      } else {
        // we append the 'next' node to the startNode:
        startNode.append(next);
      }
      // finally decrementing the counter variable for
      // the next iteration:
      counter--;
    }
  };

// calling the function:
merge(
  // retrieving the first element in the document that matches the
  // supplied CSS selector:
  get('main > div'),
  // passing in 3 as the value of 'n':
  3);
// in the rendered output note that the 'Text node' remains outside of the startNode
// the first <div> element, despite being its immediate sibling in the HTML; if you
// inspect the document with dev tools you'll see the following comment-node also
// remains outside of the first <div>.
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, system-ui;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  counter-reset: para;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  width: clamp(15rem, 70vw, 1200px);
}

div {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-block-start: 1em;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: hsl(70 80% 70% / 0.5);
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: hsl(140 80% 70% / 0.5);
}

p::first-line {
  font-style: italic;
}

p::before {
  counter-increment: para;
  content: counter(para, decimal-leading-zero) ': ';
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente minus placeat, ipsum culpa voluptates sed. Ex sapiente labore beatae, enim repellendus, maxime tempora consectetur est, laborum explicabo ab. Ratione, vitae.</p>
  </div>Text node<!-- comment node --><div>
    <p>Reprehenderit ratione laudantium fugit fuga, alias praesentium. Repellat minus eaque aliquid quisquam odio provident ab sapiente, doloremque vero fugiat voluptates itaque ratione ex, doloribus, rem cumque assumenda. Ullam, quod, ut.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Assumenda quaerat magni, voluptatem est sit quia nesciunt fuga doloribus, beatae temporibus deserunt reiciendis suscipit excepturi animi maiores itaque, iusto consectetur, perspiciatis. Minima eligendi debitis suscipit quibusdam, odit, perspiciatis commodi!</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Expedita ducimus facilis, quis architecto molestiae tempora provident officia obcaecati, repellat consectetur tempore non debitis quae dolores quaerat est maiores modi ratione similique ad consequuntur impedit asperiores numquam. Debitis, illum!</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Odit quis expedita, architecto sed eum cum sunt deserunt facilis recusandae quia animi illo est, temporibus, accusantium amet. Numquam accusantium culpa eum blanditiis magnam consectetur soluta praesentium nam earum laboriosam.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ocx4q07h/).

```js
// I don't enjoy typing all that much, so these are a couple of utilities to avoid
// typing 'document' and 'document.querySelector(...)':
const D = document,
  get = (selector, context = D) => context.querySelector(selector),
  // a simple named function, written using Arrow function syntax (as there's no
  // need to use 'this');
  // the function takes three arguments, the first of which is the
  // startNode: a reference to a node in the document, and
  // n: an Integer which is the number of siblings in the document you wish to
  // 'merge' together; this has a default argument of 0 which means the function
  // does nothing,
  // elementsOnly: Boolean, default of true; if this is true we only worry about
  // merging element-nodes (<div>,<p>...) into the startNode; if false then we
  // also merge text-nodes, comment-nodes, etc:
  merge = (startNode, n = 0, elementsOnly = true) => {
    // if there is no startNode (or startNode is falsey), we quit the function:
    if (!startNode) {
      return false;
    }
    // otherwise we initialise a counter from the supplied variable of 'n',
    // we use parseInt(), with a radix of 10 (for base-10 numbering), on
    // the supplied number in case it's somehow a string, or a number in
    // another base:
    let counter = parseInt(n, 10),
      nodeTypes = elementsOnly === true ? 'nextElementSibling' : 'nextSibling';

    // while the counter variable is truthy:
    while (counter) {

      // we assign either the startNode node's next element-sibling (if
      // elementsOnly is equal to true) or the next sibling node (if
      // elementsOnly is equal to false):
      let next = startNode[nodeTypes];

      // if there is no next-sibling node we break out of the while loop:
      if (!next) {
        break;
      }

      // if the nodeType of the 'next' node is
      // equal to 1 (so the node is an element-
      // node):
      if (next.nodeType === 1) {
        // while the element-node has a first-child:
        while (next.firstChild) {
          // we append that first-child to the startNode:
          startNode.append(next.firstChild);
        }
        // once emptied, we remove the 'next' node:
        next.remove();

        // otherwise:
      } else {
        // we append the 'next' node to the startNode:
        startNode.append(next);
      }
      // finally decrementing the counter variable for
      // the next iteration:
      counter--;
    }
  };

// calling the function:
merge(
  // retrieving the first element in the document that matches the
  // supplied CSS selector:
  get('main > div'),
  // passing in 3 as the value of 'n':
  3,
  // setting (Boolean) false as the argument for elementsOnly,
  // so this time we include all nodes not just element-nodes:
  false);
// this time the rendered output will move both the text-node and
// the HTML comment inside of the startNode (first <div> element).
```

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto, system-ui;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  counter-reset: para;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  padding: 1em;
  width: clamp(15rem, 70vw, 1200px);
}

div {
  padding: 0.5em;
}

div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-block-start: 1em;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: hsl(70 80% 70% / 0.5);
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: hsl(140 80% 70% / 0.5);
}

p::first-line {
  font-style: italic;
}

p::before {
  counter-increment: para;
  content: counter(para, decimal-leading-zero) ': ';
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente minus placeat, ipsum culpa voluptates sed. Ex sapiente labore beatae, enim repellendus, maxime tempora consectetur est, laborum explicabo ab. Ratione, vitae.</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Reprehenderit ratione laudantium fugit fuga, alias praesentium. Repellat minus eaque aliquid quisquam odio provident ab sapiente, doloremque vero fugiat voluptates itaque ratione ex, doloribus, rem cumque assumenda. Ullam, quod, ut.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- comment node -->
  <div>
    <p>Assumenda quaerat magni, voluptatem est sit quia nesciunt fuga doloribus, beatae temporibus deserunt reiciendis suscipit excepturi animi maiores itaque, iusto consectetur, perspiciatis. Minima eligendi debitis suscipit quibusdam, odit, perspiciatis
      commodi!
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Expedita ducimus facilis, quis architecto molestiae tempora provident officia obcaecati, repellat consectetur tempore non debitis quae dolores quaerat est maiores modi ratione similique ad consequuntur impedit asperiores numquam. Debitis, illum!</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Odit quis expedita, architecto sed eum cum sunt deserunt facilis recusandae quia animi illo est, temporibus, accusantium amet. Numquam accusantium culpa eum blanditiis magnam consectetur soluta praesentium nam earum laboriosam.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ocx4q07h/1/).

References:

- Arrow functions.
- `document.querySelector()`.
- `document.querySelectorAll()`.
- [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).
- [`Element.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling).
- [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).
- [`Element.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).
- [`Element.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove).
- [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).
- [`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling).
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType).
- [`while () {...}`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- JavaScript variables cannot start with a number (0-9).
- There isn't a `div` with an id of `1`.
- `$().html` is a function and must be called as `$().html()` with parentheses.

By fixing those issues and adding another line of JavaScript, you'll get a complete webpage that merges the HTML content of both `div`s into the first one, then removes the second `div`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id='one'>One</div>
<div id='two'>Two</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var one = $('#one').html();
var two = $('#two').html();
$('#one').html(one + two);
$('#two').remove();
</script>
```